# How to tell macOS that a directory that ends in ".App" is not an app

Tags: .net, macos, .net-core, osx-elcapitan, macos-sierra

In the [.NET Core installer](http://dot.net/core#macos) we create a directory named `Microsoft.NETCore.App`.  Since this directory ends in `.App`, macOS thinks that this is an application itself and it won't show the contents of the folder in the Finder.

Is there a way I can tell the OS (specifically the Finder) that this directory should be treated like a regular directory and not think it is an application?  Or is my only option to rename our directory so it doesn't end in `.App`?

Comment: right click on it and click show contents to see what is in it. or afaik rename

Comment: Bad idea... one can't expect an  `.App` to behave like a regular directory on `macOS`, just like you wouldn't expect an `.Exe` to `Windows`; certain extensions are intended to behave a particular way on it's respective OS, so I would recommend a taking different approach.